How can I use escapeinside within a minted environment with the bash lexer?
The escapeinside functionality doesn't work properly with the bash lexer. Is there any way to fix this?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{bash}
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world!"
|\textrm{Some commentary here}|
\end{minted}

\end{document}



This happens because the Bash lexer redefines the catcode for the backslash \ in order to handle shell escape sequences. This means that it cannot be used in an escapeinside sequence to start a command.
Fortunately, a workaround is possible by making another character active and defining it using csname to activate its argument. It is critical that the selected character does not appear anywhere else in your minted code. For this example, I use the question mark ?. When invoking a command, e.g. \textrm{arg}, you will instead invoke ?{textrm}{arg}, replacing the question mark with the character you've chosen.
It is important to enclose the whole thing with \begingroup/\endgroup to ensure that the catcode redefinition doesn't impact the rest of your document.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
% REPLACE THE ? WITH YOUR CHOSEN CHARACTER ON BOTH OF THE FOLLOWING LINES
\catcode`\?=\active
\def?#1{\csname #1\endcsname}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{bash}
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world!"
|?{textrm}{Some commentary here}|
\end{minted}
\endgroup

\end{document}


